# How to do OCR for multi page using (Python + AWS Textract + Lambda)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-textract

I used the code (python + AWS textract + lambda) below and The OCR success to get response for the pdf with one page

But when I test with more than one page pdf it doesn't work

need advice to OCR for multipage pdf

```
    client = boto3.client("textract")
    response = client.analyze_document(
        Document={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": 'test-bucket',
                "Name": 'testpdf.pdf',
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes=["QUERIES",],
        QueriesConfig={
            "Queries": [
                {
                "Text": "What is openning balance?",
                "Alias": "OPEN"
                },
                {
                "Text": "What is closing balance?",
                "Alias": "CLOSE"
                }
                ]
            }
        )

    data = response
```

need advice

Answer (score 1):

Multipage PDFs are only supported by the asynchronous API. So you need to use
`client.start_document_analysis` which will return a job id that you can use to fetch the results "later". You can pass an SNS topic which will be triggered once the processing is over allowing for a workflow like:

Call Amazon Textract Lambda => SNS Topic triggered => Fetch Results lambda

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract.html#Textract.Client.start_document_analysis

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, may I summarize the steps like this
(1)-> Using ```start_document_analysis``` with parameter ```Query``` and using SNS
(2)-> Get ```JOB ID```
(3)-> Use ```get_document_text_detection``` with parameter ```JOB ID```

(Question)-> Is it correct to put parameter ```Query``` in ```start_document_analysis``` ?

Comment: It is, queries are given to the `start_document_analysis` function call.